# jsp struts ; how to set formbean attribute is based on another form bean attribute

Tags: java, jsp, struts-1

I am working on a web app using JSP with struts 1.2
I have a requirement where i need to set a display a field on UI . the field value formbean attribute is based on another form bean attribute. 
I added a if check, but not sure how to set the attribute.

```
<c:when test="${person.relationship == SA || person.relationship == SP }">
//how to set person.status = married;
</c:when>
```

person is formbean and relationship and status are attributes.

Answer (score 0):

You can set like,

```
<c:when test="${person.relationship == SA || person.relationship == SP }">
    <html:text value="<%= status %>" property="person.status" size="25" maxlength="256"></html:text>
</c:when>
```

Here "status" is the run time variable derived from "form bean" or you can give some hard coded string as well.

You can use any UI element based on your requirement.

Comment: Hi gnana, thanks for the reply.  the "person.status", will be a displayed as a dropdown field.

Comment: @JoshLewis if you want to set `person.status` to the dropdown filed, show dropdown filed structure?